# Improvements on a makeshift dessicator

Tags: experimental-physics, experimental-technology

I am a first year undergrad working in a lab, and I have these Plexiglass containers that I tried to convert to [dessicators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desiccator), since the commercial bell jars are really expensive. I used these weather strips from a hardwarestore that are suppose to be moisture tight, and sealed the connections with silicone. The craftmanship is kind of poor, but I am pretty sure there are no leaks in the silicone seal. Then I used some vacuum grease between the strip and the glass. I have these containers connected and have N2 flowing through. However, even though there is gas flowing through, moisture indicators still showed (after a few of days) that the last couple boxes are not sealing properly.

I was wondering if you guys have any ideas on improving the seals, or improving the system in general to help prolonging the period which the containers can seal properly.

Couldn't post any images since I'm new here =(

Comment: Vaguely related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/44784/how-to-determine-whether-a-large-container-is-air-tight

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is better craftsmanship and them more sealant---just slather it on there, you are not getting graded on neatness are you?